# How to write below bullet

Tags: beamer, subscripts

I have to write something under the symbol `\bullet` in `Latex`. Is it possible?
I'm using the class `beamer`.
Here it is an example of a frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> Products Market\mbox{}\\ \footnotesize{where $p_{i,t}=u_{i,t}$, with $u_{i,t}\sim u[0,2]$}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item<2-> Credit Market \mbox{} \vspace{0.2cm} \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm} $\bullet_{bank} \xrightarrow{loan} \bullet$}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\item<3-> Interbank Market\mbox{} \vspace{0.08cm} \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm} $\bullet \xrightarrow{loan} \bullet$}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

In particular I want to write "bank" under the bullet, while now it is only in `subscript`.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a new math operator (load `amsmath` package)

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mbullet}{\bullet}
```

and use (note the `\text{}` command to write text inside math mode)

```
$\mbullet\limits_{\text{bank}} \xrightarrow{\text{loan}} \bullet$
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\underset` from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath):

```
$\underset{bank}{\bullet}$
```

Mind you, this is "wrong" as bank is being typeset as mathematics so that it looks like `b*a*n*k`. It is better to write:

```
$\underset{\text{bank}}{\bullet}$
```

Finally, your empty `\mbox` commands seem redundant. Here is how I would write your full MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> Products Market\\ \footnotesize{where $p_{i,t}=u_{i,t}$, with $u_{i,t}\sim u[0,2]$}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \item<2-> Credit Market \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm}
  $\underset{\text{bank}}\bullet \xrightarrow{\text{loan}} \bullet$}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \item<3-> Interbank Market \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm} $\bullet \xrightarrow{\text{loan}} \bullet$}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not TikZ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    bullet/.style = {
        circle,
        inner sep = 0,
        outer sep = 0,
        minimum size = .8ex,
        fill=black,
        label=below:{\tiny #1},
        label distance=0,
    },
    bullet/.default = {\phantom{bank}},
    shorten >=1ex,
    shorten <=1ex,
    baseline=-.4ex,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\itemsep=0.5cm
\item<1->
    Products Market\\
    \footnotesize{where $p_{i,t}=u_{i,t}$, with $u_{i,t}\sim u[0,2]$}
\item<2->
    Credit Market\\
    \footnotesize{where
        \tikz \draw[->]
          node[bullet=bank](A) {}
          node[bullet     ](B) at (1,0){}
          (A) --node[above]{\tiny loan} (B);
    }
\item<3->
    Interbank Market\mbox{} \vspace{0.08cm} \\
    \footnotesize{where
        \tikz \draw[->]
          node[bullet     ](A) {}
          node[bullet=bank](B) at (1,0){}
          (A) --node[above]{\tiny loan} (B);
    }
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: you can set the vspace between items by setting `\itemsep` instead of manually putting `\vspace`s

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Using `tikz` here seems an overkill...

Comment: just giving another option. Maybe more complex diagrams come after that slide...

Comment: (and `pgf` is already loaded by `beamer` anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with the `stackengine` package and the `clap` command from `mathtools`. I defined an `\underbullet` command that takes as argument the text below the bullet, and optionally the vertical distance  between the bullet and the text:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\underbullet[2][0pt]{\stackunder[#1]{\textbullet}{\tiny\clap{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> Products Market\\ \footnotesize{where $p_{i,t}=u_{i,t}$, with $u_{i,t} ∼ u[0,2]$}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \item<2-> Credit Market \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm}
    \underbullet{bank}}${}\xrightarrow{\text{loan}}\bullet$
      \vspace{0.5cm}
      \item<3-> Interbank Market \\ \footnotesize{where \hspace{0.1cm} $\bullet \xrightarrow{\text{loan}} \bullet$}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `\underset` command from the `amsmath` package can do this in math mode. The first argument is the thing to put below the second argument (which will not be moved upward).

```
$ \underset{\text{bank}}{\bullet} $
```

There is also `\overset` for placing something above instead of below.